# Making a big old site mobile friendly: navigation

Tags: css, html, mobile, viewport, navigationbar

I have a big old site that I have been growing over the years, 
[www.vintagewatchstraps.com](http://www.vintagewatchstraps.com). Almost all pages validate as HTML5.

Now Google has started grumbling that it isn't mobile friendly. I can add the "meta name=viewport" business, and I understand that I will need to change things like widths to be in % rather than pixels, but the thing that is bothering me most is the navigation.

I have been reading up about making a mobile friendly CSS navigation bar, at Medialoot and Lisa Catalano, but the examples they give have only a few pages. If I displayed my navigation as a vertical list on a small screen as they suggest, my 70+ navigation links would go on forever. All the examples of adapting a site to mobile that I have found just don't cover sites having lots of content and pages.

Any suggestions as to how to deal with this would be gratefully received.

Kind regards - David

Answer (score 0):

Some ideas:

- do you actually need all those links in the menu? Try only including the main things people want to see, as people aren't likely to read your entire website on a mobile device anyway.
- have two layers of menus: a heading reveals another slide out menu with subcategories
- put a search box at the top of your menu